# Horizontal scrolling with sticky div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, horizontal-scrolling

Im trying to do a horizontal navigation with some fixed/sticky elements.
When the user scroll the page, some divs have to remain stuck on the left edge.

Here a fiddle of what i want to do :

http://jsfiddle.net/rQUeL/

```
css

.container>div {

display:block;
float:left;
}

.container { 
height:100%; display:block; background:grey; float:left; width:2000px;
}

.cover{
width:25%; height:100%; background:blue; }

.menu{
width:90px; height:90px; background:green; margin-left:100px; }

.menu.fixed{
}

.cover.fixed{
}

.content{
width:500px; height:100px; background:red; }



<div class="container">
<div class="cover" >
       <div class="menu">Menu</div>
</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
```

When the green square reach the left edge, the green and the blue elements have to be fixed , and the red content go below.

I believe it can be do jQuery...

Thank you for your help.

Sebastien

Answer (score 2):

You basically change the class when the scroll length is above a certain number 
 (in this case `margin-left` from `.menu`)

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var sl = $(this).scrollLeft();
    if (sl > 100) { // 100 is margin-left from .menu
        $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
        $('.cover').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
        $('.cover').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

PS: I have no idea what you want with the red element

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/rQUeL/5/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's almost that, but the blue content must keep its position when the green one reach the border, currently there is a gap. The red content must follow the blue cover and begin to slide under when the green square reach the border. Thanks @Spokey

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and couldn't find any solutions using CSS alone. so I made jQuery plugin that solves this issue. You can find it [here](https://github.com/phillt/makeSticky).

[Well, I had a great gif here demonstrating what it does but SO doesn't support it. You'll have to click this to see it.](https://github.com/phillt/makeSticky/raw/master/img/gif.gif)

Now, before you yell at me, let me yell at you first. This is a **BYOCSS**. So if you're looking for something that will take care of the CSS for you, keep looking. All you have to do is style the header element in an absolute position.

This plugin is still in development and needs some improvements. It's kinda jittery when you scroll. You can ease the jittering with a CSS3 `transition: 90ms;`

This is just a starting point, if you would like to contribute to it, fork it and see what you can do.